# Android. ListView. Add items dynamically

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

There is ListView which uses my own CustomArrayAdapter. I can't dynamically add items to ListView. ListView is component of Fragment.

```
if(!recentItems.isEmpty()) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            MyFragment.listAdapter.addItems(recentItems);           
            MyFragment.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                      
        }                   
    });                             
}
```

All new items are added to ArrayList of my CustomArrayAdapter.

```
private ArrayList<ListItem> values;

public void addItems(ArrayList<ListItem> list) {        
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        for(ListItem item : list) {
            values.add(item);
        }           
    } else {
        values.addAll(list);
    }               
}
```

I have read lot of suggestions but till now none of them worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

call notifyDataSetChange() after you add the values.

Comment: There I should call? As you can see I call `notifyDataSetChange` method after `addItems` method.

Comment: He is doing I think the same.

Comment: oops sorry. Are you sure that recentItems isn't empty?

Comment: also make sure your getCount function returns the size of values and not a constant size

Comment: I toggled breakpoint in `addItems` method. Passed `recentItems` list  isn't empty.

Comment: check the getCount value after notifyDataSetChanged